# Assembla's Cornerstone (fake) API to listen for own commits

Tags: git, api, svn, assembla, cornerstone

in a previous project I had the chance to listen for git uploads to post it in another software like RocketChat, Slack, etc. But Im working with Cornerstone now. Is there any way to do the same? I can't find a Cornerstone API.